# How does Google file document objects?

Tags: filesystems, google-drive-api, gfs

How does Google store and organize documents, such as documents in Google Docs?
I'd like to ask which file system Google uses, but I know it uses GFS, a distributed file system for storing huge files, basically the huge databases containing, among other things, also the Documents I am interested in.

My question is: Is each document a record in a DB? And how does it identify documents in a hierarchical system, such as web pages? How does it relate them, or represent the hierarchical structure, if needed?

It looks like Google created his own "file system" in a DB (besides the underlying GFS).
Does anyone know any specification or its working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google Drive, then yes, databases are involved, but unfortunately I can't really share any of the confidential details, sorry.

p.s. check out the GFS paper: http://research.google.com/archive/gfs.html

Comment: Thanks, at least you saved me time trying to look for the details :)

Comment: Can i assume google drive is a client application, where gfs is the backbone of the storage, every chunk CRUD operation in google drive actually is happening on GFS